# Stubber has no boto3 attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3, stub

```
    self.cf_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    self.cf_client_stubber = Stubber(self.cf_client)

    print(f" cc {type(self.cf_client_stubber)}")

    self.cf_client_stubber.add_response("describe_stacks", self.cf_describe_response,
                                        self.cf_describe_params)
    self.cf_client_stubber.activate()

    stackList = self.cf_client_stubber.describe_stacks(StackName=self.cf_stack_name, NextToken='xyz')
```

whenever I run this method with pytest, I encounter the following error:

```
E           AttributeError: 'Stubber' object has no attribute 'describe_stacks'

python/src/example.py:26: AttributeError
```

Any insight as to what the main problem would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem.

1. When you are calling the method, don't use the stubber. Use the actual boto3 client.
2. Put the stubber methods in the order of which the method you are testing methods you will invoke like `add_reponse`. For example, if `describe_stacks` is called before `delete_stack`, then in the test add `describe_stacks` before `delete_stack`; otherwise, the methods will not be found.

Comment: Can you provide you working code after implementing #1 & #2 as you mentioned? I'm running into the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to add an example since the accepted answer did not.

Right from the [docs](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html).

Note the use of the `s3` client to make the request and not the stubber.

```
service_response = s3.list_objects(Bucket='test-bucket')
```

```
import datetime
import botocore.session
from botocore.stub import Stubber


s3 = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('s3')
stubber = Stubber(s3)

response = {
    'IsTruncated': False,
    'Name': 'test-bucket',
    'MaxKeys': 1000, 'Prefix': '',
    'Contents': [{
        'Key': 'test.txt',
        'ETag': '"abc123"',
        'StorageClass': 'STANDARD',
        'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 20, 22, 9),
        'Owner': {'ID': 'abc123', 'DisplayName': 'myname'},
        'Size': 14814
    }],
    'EncodingType': 'url',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': 'abc123',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HostId': 'abc123'
    },
    'Marker': ''
}

expected_params = {'Bucket': 'test-bucket'}

stubber.add_response('list_objects', response, expected_params)
stubber.activate()

service_response = s3.list_objects(Bucket='test-bucket')
assert service_response == response
```

If you try to use the stubber to make the request you will get the above error

> AttributeError: 'Stubber' object has no attribute ...